# ObjectiveC error handling for void functions

Tags: objective-c, error-handling

I have a function along the lines of

```
- (void)doSomeFunctionWithError:(NSError **)error;
```

If the function does result in an error, how am I supposed to check that an error occurred? Apple recommends to check the return value for nil, but obviously I cannot do that here. I'm currently just checking if the error value is not nil, but it seems that is frowned upon.

Comment: Clarify: are you "checking" from inside or outside the function? Are you the caller or the implementor (author) of this function?

Comment: If you are the caller, the author is supposed to return a BOOL so that you know whether an error occurred.

Comment: If you are the author, then do what I just said; return BOOL, not void, indicating whether things went well or not.

Comment: I'm the caller, so I'll take your advice and notify the author to return a BOOL value instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your confusion is that whoever is supplying this method has written it incorrectly. Apple is right: you should not check the value of an NSError pointer unless you know in advance that there is an NSError at the other end of the pointer. The method is supposed to return something that tells you this.

The correct convention, if the method does not return something-or-nil as an indicator of whether things went well, is to return a BOOL, like this:

```
- (BOOL)doSomeFunctionWithError:(NSError **)error;
```

That way, you have something to check. Look, for instance, at NSFileManager; a lot of its methods have this pattern (see e.g. [`linkItemAtURL:...`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/linkItemAtURL%3atoURL%3aerror%3a)).